# Why can't it find my celery config file?

Tags: python, django, celery

> /home/myuser/mysite-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/loaders/default.py:53:
>   NotConfigured: No celeryconfig.py
>   module found! Please make sure it
>   exists and is available to Python.
>   NotConfigured)

I even defined it in my /etc/profile and also in my virtual environment's "activate". But it's not reading it.

Comment: Stupid question... (because I've done this) when python executes is it running the correct version. I've worked on systems with 2 versions of python... don't ask.

Answer (score 39):

**Now in Celery 4.1 you can solve that problem by that code(the easiest way):**

```
import celeryconfig

from celery import Celery

app = Celery()
app.config_from_object(celeryconfig)
```

For Example small **celeryconfig.py** :

```
BROKER_URL = 'pyamqp://'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost'
CELERY_ROUTES = {'task_name': {'queue': 'queue_name_for_task'}}
```

---

**Also very simple way:**

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks')

app.conf.update(
    result_expires=60,
    task_acks_late=True,
    broker_url='pyamqp://',
    result_backend='redis://localhost'
)
```

---

**Or Using a configuration class/object:**

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery()

class Config:
    enable_utc = True
    timezone = 'Europe/London'

app.config_from_object(Config)
# or using the fully qualified name of the object:
#   app.config_from_object('module:Config')
```

---

**Or how was mentioned by setting CELERY_CONFIG_MODULE**

```
import os
from celery import Celery

#: Set default configuration module name
os.environ.setdefault('CELERY_CONFIG_MODULE', 'celeryconfig')

app = Celery()
app.config_from_envvar('CELERY_CONFIG_MODULE')
```

---

**Also see:**

- **Create config:** http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/application.html#configuration
- **Configuration fields:** http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html

Comment: How to do it when you have just the filename?  /path/to/filename.py

Comment: @010110110101 First option seems to be right for you. See in the answer I have added some explanation for first option. If it isn't clear I'm ready to help.

Comment: To make it even easier the calls to `config_from_object` can be omitted by setting the config directly on `Celery()` using the keyword argument `config_source` i.e. `app = Celery(config_source=celeryconfig)`

Answer (score 22):

I had a similar problem with my tasks module. A simple

```
# celery config is in a non-standard location
import os
os.environ['CELERY_CONFIG_MODULE'] = 'mypackage.celeryconfig'
```

in my package's `__init__.py` solved this problem.

Comment: As recommended in [Celery's recommendations for Django](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html), `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')` in the celery configuration file before `app = Celery('tasks')` is called should work well, especially if you wanted to update your settings file dynamically later.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have celeryconfig.py in the same location you are running 'celeryd' or otherwise make sure its is available on the Python path.

Answer (score 3):

you can work around this with the environment... or, use --config:  it requires

1. a path relative to CELERY_CHDIR from /etc/defaults/celeryd
2. a python module name, not a filename.

The error message could probably use these two facts.