# Where should I put the Celery configuration file?

Tags: python, celery

The celery documentation helpfully [gives an example of a configuration file](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/configuration.html#example-configuration-file), but it is less clear on where to put this file, or how to ensure that the worker reads this config file when it boots.

celery.py defines an object of type `celery.Celery` called `app`, which is what I use to decorate all my tasks. All of the tasks are in `/myproj/tasks/`.

My directory structure is a bit like this:

```
/myproj/celery.py
       /celeryconfig.py # my settings
       /tasks/ # tasks go here
```

Is there something I can put into `celery.py` which makes it load the `celeryconfig.py` file, or do I need to specify it on the worker command-line arguments?

Here's what my config file looks like right now:

```
## Broker settings.
broker_url = "pyamqp://admin:ypass@mq:5672"

# List of modules to import when the Celery worker starts.
imports = ('stoneid.tasks',)
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763072/why-cant-it-find-my-celery-config-file

Answer (score 14):

After reading your question, I have understood that you are confused about where to keep the config file and how to import those.

> Celery has many ways to load config file. One of those is [config_from_object](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/app/base.html#Celery.config_from_object).

That will be a simple python file and consist of celery configs.
For your example  `celeryconfig.py` will consists:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
```

and `celery.py` will contains below code.

```
app = Celery('myproj')
default_config = 'myproj.celeryconfig'
app.config_from_object(default_config)
```

If you follow above instruction, you do not need to pass conf via command line.

Comment: Can the `celeryconfig.py` file also contain `imports`? Such as `import os` to gather a env var for a config variable?

Comment: Did not try and test. I hope so. Please have a try and let us know.

Comment: Thank you! Given it a go, it seems to work with my little experiment here